# SQL query of related items from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Previous question: [SQL query of relationship between two items from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993179/sql-query-of-relationship-between-two-items-from-the-same-table).

I'd like to be able to relate items from the same table with a join table. Similarly to question above but I was wondering if its possible to query all items from the table linked to each other.

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ba76/1/0)**

```
entries
  id
  name
similars (join table connecting two entries)
  one_id
  two_id


car - train 
    \
      bicycle - shopping cart
```

Would it be possible to query all items linked to "bicycle" and get results like:

```
Entry   | Similar_to 
---------------------
Bicycle | Shopping cart
Bicycle | Car
Bicycle | Train
```

**update:**

It seems like i need recursion to do this so i moved from mysql to postgresql.
Currently wondering how to accomplish recursion both ways using the join table. Here's a the table setup and query that works going one way on the linked list:

```
CREATE TABLE entries 
( 
  id serial primary key, 
  name varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO entries
(name)
VALUES
('Car'),
('Train'),
('Bicycle'),
('Shopping cart'),
('Node'),
('Skis'),
('Skates');

CREATE TABLE similars
(
  one_id int,
  two_id int
);

INSERT INTO similars
(one_id, two_id)
VALUES
(1, 2), 
(1, 3),
(3, 4),
(6, 7);
```

query, now with extra postgresql

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp AS
(
  SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name = 'Bicycle'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT e.*
  FROM entries AS e
  LEFT JOIN similars AS s 
  ON e.id = s.two_id
  JOIN temp l
  ON s.one_id = l.id
)
SELECT * FROM temp;
```

With that I get results that would work great although still need to figure out how to get the rest of them.

```
ID  NAME
3   Bicycle
4   Shopping cart
```

[New SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3ffee/34/0). If anyone knows how to get results going both directions on the linked list would be great.

Comment: I might just not be smart enough, but I can't figure out what you are asking.  Could you supply some sample output?

Comment: Added some output to what i would be looking for

Comment: Ok I get it now.. you want bicycle to be listed first in all cases. regardless if it's in position 1 or 2 of the similar's table.

Comment: I think what you want is recusion. In SQL Server that would be done with a recursive CTE but I don't know if my sql has those. You might be stuck with some type of cursor.

Comment: mysql does not. it'd have to be done in a stored procedure.

Comment: Perhaps this fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ba76/9/0  it returns the results of bicycle in the left most column and the similar_to in the right most column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sweet, doubly linked list with UNION instead of UNION ALL to handle already traveled entries seems to work fine.

```
INSERT INTO similars
(one_id, two_id)
VALUES
(1, 2), 
(2, 1),
(1, 3),
(3, 1),
(3, 4),
(4, 3),
(6, 7),
(7, 6);

WITH RECURSIVE linked_list AS
(
  SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name = 'Bicycle'

  UNION 

  SELECT e.*
  FROM entries e
  LEFT JOIN similars s 
  ON e.id = s.one_id
  JOIN linked_list l
  ON s.two_id = l.id

)
SELECT * FROM linked_list;
```

Results for Bicycle:

```
ID  NAME
3   Bicycle
1   Car
4   Shopping cart
2   Train
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0643a/7/0). Complete list now retrieved! Rolling with this one unless anyone has an idea how to do this with single links.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.name as "Entry",
       es.name as "Similar_To"
from entries e
inner join similars s
on e.id = s.one_id
inner join entries es
on s.two_id = es.id
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand proprly your question, you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT e1.*, e2.* 
FROM similars AS sim
JOIN entries as e1 ON sim.one_id = e1.id
JOIN entries as e2 ON sim.two_id = e2.id
WHERE 'Bicycle' IN (e1.name, e2.name);
```

`IN` clause can be also replaced with `e1.name='Bicycle' OR e2.name = 'Bicycle'`